# Boost thread memory usage on 64bit linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, memory, boost

I have been using boost threads on 32bit linux for some time and am very happy with their performance so far. Recently the project was moved to a 64bit platform and we saw a huge increase in memory usage (from about 2.5gb to 16-17gb). I have done profiling and found that the boost threads are the source of the huge allocation. Each thread is allocating about 10x what it was doing on 32bit.

I profiled using valgrind's massif and have confirmed the issue using only boost threads in a separate test application. I also tried using std::threads instead and these do not exhibit the large memory allocation issue.

I am wondering if anyone else has seen this behaviour and knows what the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem. This is *virtual* memory, and each 64-bit process can allocate terabytes of virtual memory on every modern operating system. It's basically free and there's no reason to care about how much of it used.

It's basically just reserved space for thread stacks. You can reduce it, if you want, by changing the default stack size. But there's absolutely no reason to.

Comment: I understand that it is virtual memory, but in this case it is not for thread stacks. Thread stacks default to 8mb and this shows separately in the profiling results. Regardless of the impact I would like to know why so much is being allocated.

Comment: @radman: It's because there is absolutely no reason not to. If you could have either $100 or $1,000,000, and there was no downside to taking the million, why would you take the $100? Programmers have been caused no end of pain due to the scarcity of virtual memory -- we are finally free of that on 64-bit operating systems. When something is effectively boundless, you don't have to be miserly about it. You can trade it off for *anything* -- performance, convenience, portability, re-usability, maintainability ... whatever.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1.  stack size of per-thread

use pthread_attr_getstacksize to view. use boost::thread::attributes to change (pthread_attr_setstacksize).

#### 2. pre-mmap for per-thread in glibc's malloc

gdb example of boost.thread

```
0  0x000000000040ffe0 in boost::detail::get_once_per_thread_epoch() ()  
1  0x0000000000407c12 in void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)()) [clone .constprop.120] ()  
2  0x00000000004082cf in thread_proxy ()  
3  0x000000000041120a in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff7ffd700) at pthread_create.c:308  
4  0x00000000004c5cf9 in clone ()  
5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

you will discover `data=malloc(sizeof(boost::uintmax_t));` in get_once_per_thread_epoch ( **boost_1_50_0/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp** )

continue

```
1  0x000000000041a0d3 in new_heap ()  
2  0x000000000041b045 in arena_get2.isra.5.part.6 ()  
3  0x000000000041ed13 in malloc ()  
4  0x0000000000401b1a in test () at pthread_malloc_8byte.cc:9  
5  0x0000000000402d3a in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff7ffd700) at pthread_create.c:308  
6  0x00000000004413d9 in clone ()  
7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

in new_heap function (**glibc-2.15\malloc\arena.c**), it will pre-mmap 64M memory for per-thread in 64bit os. in other words, per-thread will use *64M + 8M (default thread stack) = 72M*.

```
glibc-2.15\ChangeLog.17  
2009-03-13  Ulrich Drepper  <drepper@redhat.com>  
  * malloc/malloc.c: Implement PER_THREAD and ATOMIC_FASTBINS features.  
  * malloc/arena.c: Likewise.  
  * malloc/hooks.c: Likewise.
```

http://wuerping.github.io/blog/malloc_per_thread.html